Error when implementing a custom event listener for Keycloak
I'm trying to create a custom event listener for Keycloak by implementing a Service Provider Interface (SPI). This listener should use RabbitMQ to publish an event whenever a user is registered, updated or deleted.
I generate the jar file using the mvn clean package command, add the file to the providers folder, but whenever I try to save the event listener in Keycloak, the following error message appears:
Error saving event listener: For more on this error consult the server log at the debug level.
I've already tried using the 'maven-assembly-plugin' and the 'maven-shade-plugin' in the pom.xml, but the problem remains the same.
Does anyone know how to solve it?
Error in keycloak container log in docker-compose:
2024-08-10 12:59:58,056 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-4) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory
        at com.gustavo.keycloakUserSync.CustomEventListenerProvider.<init>(CustomEventListenerProvider.java:28)
        at com.gustavo.keycloakUserSync.CustomEventListenerProviderFactory.create(CustomEventListenerProviderFactory.java:15)
        at com.gustavo.keycloakUserSync.CustomEventListenerProviderFactory.create(CustomEventListenerProviderFactory.java:9)
        at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:195)
        at org.keycloak.models.KeycloakBeanProducer_ProducerMethod_getKeycloakSession_XoSEUTXOsE3bpqXlGMAykCiECUM_ClientProxy.getProvider(Unknown Source)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminEventBuilder.lambda$addListeners$0(AdminEventBuilder.java:136)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminEventBuilder.addListeners(AdminEventBuilder.java:135)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminEventBuilder.refreshRealmEventsConfig(AdminEventBuilder.java:119)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource.updateRealmEventsConfig(RealmAdminResource.java:746)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource$quarkusrestinvoker$updateRealmEventsConfig_819a7611841478b25afbae197af50b540fbebc6f.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:115)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:65)
        ... 30 more

POM.XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.gustavo</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-user-sync</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>keycloak-user-sync</name>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <jar.finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jar.finalName>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.10.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
          </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <finalName>${jar.finalName}</finalName>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>-->
        
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>

The full implementation: https://github.com/GustavoSC1/keycloak-user-sync

The error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is due to maven not including dependencies into the JAR. The solution here is to create a fat JAR with the maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin.
In your case, you specified the build plugin under the pluginManagement section, but forgot to include the main <plugins/> section. The management section is to define configurations and versions to use, not to import the plugins.
A correct pom would look like this:
<build>
    <!-- Here you specify configurations -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <!-- Here you specify which plugins to import -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

